# PHP Fatal Error: Failed to create COM object: Server Execution Failed

Tags: php, excel, com, access-denied, uncaught-exception

I am using PHP to create a COM object to read and write to an excel file but when I run this script it gives me this error:

> Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object 'excel.application':**Access is denied.**

Then I followed these [instructions](http://www.figured-it-out.com/figured-out.php?sid=24) and now I'm getting the following error message:

> PHP Fatal Error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `excel.application':**Sever execution failed**

```
<?php
 $excel = new COM("excel.application") or die ("Cannot open Excel");
?>
```

Does any one have an explanation for this error message or solutions?

Comment: @user555 I started out using PHPExcel but my job requires that I use OLE instead because they have OLE formatting scripts already written. They don't want me to have to reinvent the wheel again.

Comment: What server are you using (Apache/IIS)? Also check the system event log for possible DCOM events related to your problem.

Comment: @user555 I am using IIS and I do not see any related DCOM events. I've looked in the php log and it says 'Failed to create COM object `excel.application':Sever execution failed'

Comment: Tried your code on Windows 8/IIS with the permission settings you linked and it seem to work. Also settings such promiscuous permissions (everybody) for DCOM objects might not be such a good idea.

Comment: I am limited to IIS 7.5 and Windows 7 so unfortunately I cannot try your suggestion. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @klm10 were you able to figure this out yet?